# grep command in linux using " in regex

Tags: regex, linux, grep, quotes

I have the following linux cmd:

```
grep -o file.txt "\"uri\":\".{1,}\""
```

The text i have is the following:

```
"some characters here","uri":"some_URI*Here.^%$#!", "again a set of irrelevant characters"
```

Of course the output i want to have is:

```
"uri":"some_URI*Here.^%$#!"
```

Why dont i have the correct output? Because of the " required by the grep which mix with " in my text? How to fix it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following regex:

```
grep -oE '"uri":".[^"]+"' inputFile
```

Original poster provided a regex that is almost correct but have some flaws, below is his/her version and a corrected one:

```
grep -o  inputFile "\"uri\":".{1,}\""   # wrong
grep -oE '"uri":"[^"]{1,}"' inputFile   # correct
```

The problems with the first use of grep are:

- inputFile should come after the regex, not before
- Needs `-E` flag for `{1,}` to work
- Better use single quotes outside so that double quotes need no be escaped
- Need to use `[^"]` character class instead of `.`

Comment: Why do you have `.` before `[^"]+` ?

Comment: @anubhava That looks like a leftover from the question's `.{1,}`.

Answer (score 1):

Either

```
 grep -oE "\"uri\":\"[^\"]{1,}\"" file.txt
```

or

```
grep -o "\"uri\":\"[^\"]\\{1,\\}\"" file.txt
```

will leave out the trailing irrelevant characters.

Explanation:

- Your `grep` command was listing `file.txt` before the pattern, but `grep` requires pattern first, then files.
- Instead of `.`, you need `[^\"]` to match the characters between the quotes.  That is because `.` will match a `"` itself, so `.{1,}` matches right through the intervening double quotes ("greedy matching").

The two options are:

- with `-E`, `grep` uses extended regular expressions, in which `{}` are automatically range operators.
- without `-E`, you need to use backslashes to mark the `{}` as range operators instead of literal characters.  `\{1,\}` is the regex syntax.  Since you are in a shell double-quoted string, you need to escape the backslashes, whence `\\{1,\\}`.

To test shell quoting, an easy way is to use `echo`.  For example, in bash:

```
$ echo grep -o "\"uri\":\"[^\"]\\{1,\\}\"" file.txt
grep -o "uri":"[^"]\{1,\}" file.txt
```

That shows, for example, that the `\\` in the pattern have been collapsed to a single `\`.

Comment: To see what the shell will do to a line, you can also use readline's [`shell-expand-line`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-shell_002dexpand_002dline-_0028M_002dC_002de_0029), by default bound to Meta + Ctrl + e (`M-C-e`).